# App disappeared in Itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I created an app in iTunes Connect this morning. I entered some information for the app, I uploaded a logo and I created an article (in-app purchase).

After lunch (in 2 hours), when I come back, I see this app disappeared from Itunes Connect and I can't find it any more. And when I try to created another time this app, I was told that the bundle id is used.

Answer (score 3):

Problem resolved by apple, it was a bug.

Comment: Did you need to contact Apple or did it resolve itself after some time?

Comment: Yes, you should contact Apple with a detailed description of bug and screenshots. Don't forget to mention which navigator you use.

Answer (score 2):

Check the right side of nav bar where it has grid and list view. Use the dropdown to select the sort of apps you want to see.